# How to find the smallest interval of convergence for a given power series that has unknowns?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

For example, finding the smallest interval of convergence for given series: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k (x-5)^k$ where for $x=9$ is known to be convergent and for $x=10$ divergent. Also, just for the sake of conceptualizing things, please include the largest possible interval as well.

I know how to find the interval of convergence, radius of convergence, and largest open interval for a series with knowns, but I'm not so sure about the unknowns. For this question, I'm thinking that the largest interval of convergence will be $x\in (0, 10)$ and that the smallest would be $(1,9)$. Also, how do I know if I should include the bounds for a series with unknowns like this one. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use, please, LaTeX.

Comment: I changed it. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You are doing well. For the bounds - the *largest* interval will contain $0,$ it is $[0,10).$ The smallest is $(1,9]$ because contains $9.$ The bounds are usually checked extra. It is needed to know $a_k$ for this computation.

Comment: Quick question. What exactly do you mean by checked extra? The ratio test cannot be applied here because of the unknown coefficient. Right? And for that same reason, the unknown coefficient, this series is not necessarily geometric; so, I cannot use the geometric series test. The Nth Term Test cannot be applied either. Please explain. Thanks in advance. Your help is well appreciated.